Cmake with VSCode on Windows: how to set build tool properly?
I am accustomed to using Visual Studio code with CMake on a Mac. Now I'm setting out to do the same thing under Windows, because I want to build my game cross-platform. But things aren't working the same.
Steps taken:

Install VSCode, the C++ extension, and the CMake extension.
Install Visual Studio community edition to get its compilers.
Install CMake.  It is located in   C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe
Select a kit: (I chose the last option shown below)

But at this point, things go awry. The CMake extension attempts to configure things and fails with


[cmake] CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program
corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.
You probably need to select a different build tool.

I do have an install of Msys2, so MinGW stuff should be in there I believe. But a search of the hard drive does not find anything named "MinGW Makefiles".
But I'd really rather not mix Visual Studio stuff and MinGW stuff if I can help it. (I have installed more things while poking around than I really wanted to.) But how did this build tool get selected, how might I select a different one, and is there an obvious one to choose? Or do I need to install something?

did you set environment variables for MinGW?

You should try "Visual Studio Community 2022 Release amd64" supposing you have a x86_64 machine.
otherwise if you have cmake in your PATH (i.e. you add C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\ to your user or all user env variable).
ref: Adding a directory to the PATH environment variable in Windows
You can try cmake -G in a git bash or vs cmd to see the default selected generator, should be VS 2022 on windows...
ref: https://git-scm.com/downloads/win
Otherwise on Windows, you can also use Visual Studio since it has the CMake builtin support.

And to answer the other part of the question, how the build tool is selected:
Extensions > CMake Tools > gear icon > Extension Settings > CMake:Generator
